# Ehcache not cleaning up peer listeners after startup failure

Tags: java, ehcache

I have a problem where ehcache is not cleaning up its listeners after the app fails to start.  Basically after a failed start, it then tries to establish a listener on the remoteObjectPort 40003, and fails due to the port already being in use:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 40003; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
...
```

Even though the app is stopped, the listeners are still running on those ports:

```
[root@server logs]# netstat -tulpn | grep 4000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40001               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14946/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40003               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14946/java
```

This is the relevant config in my ehcache.xml file:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory 
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                    multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                    multicastGroupPort=40002,
                    timeToLive=64"
    />



    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="port=40001,remoteObjectPort=40003,
                    socketTimeoutMillis=20000"/>
```

Is there any way to create a @PreDestroy method in my Application.java where I can explicity kill any running ehcache listeners running in the container?

Edit: Here is how I'm initialising EhCache within spring:

```
@EnableCaching
...
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

...

    @Bean
    public EhCacheCacheManager gdaCacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("cache/ehcache.xml"));
        factory.setShared(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

I'm also setting the following properties within my hibernate config to enable 2nd level caching with ehcache:

```
properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
properties.put("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "/cache/ehcache.xml");
```

Comment: Please add more information on your application lifecycle. From the question I gather you are using Spring. And I confirm that if the `CacheManager` was initialised properly, it is better to shut it down cleanly.

Comment: @LouisJacomet done.. does that help at all?